# Why isn't Frieza permanently in his golden form?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

In *Dragon Ball Super*, Frieza is shown to have surpassed the limitation of his golden form, the stamina drain.

Why isn't he permanently in this form? Is there anything stopping him from doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Using any form of transformation requires some amount of Stamina irrespective of however well you adapt to the form and you master the form.

For example, an exhausted Goku or Vegeta, wouldn't be able to turn into a Super Saiyan if their stamina is completely depleted. One good example is in *Dragon Ball Super Episode 128*, Vegeta's stamina is completely depleted and he isn't even able to turn into a regular Super Saiyan during his fight with Jiren,  [which you can see here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7BXRfk9uGQ) And it is obviously fair to say, Goku and Vegeta should have perfect mastery of the Super Saiyan forms by now.

Frieza's Golden form is immensely powerful and the stronger the transformation, it wastes greater stamina and usually has a greater toll on the body. Further proof of this is when Frieza fights Cabba. After Frieza turns into his Golden form and completely overwhelms SSJ2 Cabba, he says something along the lines of,  *"Spending excess stamina on trash is such a waste"*, [which you can see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwWDAv0QLz0).

When Frieza mastered the transformation, what he basically did was begin to use the transformation as optimally as he could. In other words, you could compare it to Goku and Vegeta using Super Saiyan Blue as optimally as they can. Even though you could say they have the Super Saiyan Blue transformation mastered, they would rather use the Super Saiyan forms or fight in their base against a weaker opponent than waste excess stamina in a much more powerful form. This is why Frieza only transforms into his Golden Form when he has an opponent who he cannot defeat in his final form.

Answer (score 0):

Well, he still has stamina problems, but let's say he didn't. The reason why he doesn't stay in that form is the same reason Goku doesn't stay in Super saiyan, even though he mastered that form can sleep in that form with no stamina drain.

It's just because they don't want to.